# Will CPL <= DPL only be checked when loading to segment register?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, memory-segmentation, kernel-mode

I'm wondering if we will check CPL <= DPL when we do a mov statement without loading to a segment register. Like:

```
mov %fs:(%eax), %ebx
```

I'm wondering this because I was thinking about what will happen if there is a flaw in operating system: OS sets %fs to 0x10 (the kernel data) in kernel mode, and forgot to set it back when returning to user mode. That way, will we be able to access kernel data?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to end up with the situation you described. The CPU clears `ds`, `es`, `fs` and `gs` during an inter-privilege return (from more to less privileged, that's the only way to demote your privileges IIRC) if they are too privileged for the target. `ss` is loaded from the stack and its DPL explicitly check against the CPL. So the CPU only needs to check the privileges when loading the segments. This makes sense as it is an expensive operation.

Comment: Modern operating systems don’t use segmentation to restrict user-mode access to kernel data. Instead, kernel data is protected using paging. So even if  an OS could make the mistake you describe, it wouldn’t allow access. Any memory accessible using FS is also accessible using a linear address with DS (which has a base of 0).

Comment: @Margaret, as far as I know, sysexit and sysret don’t perform that check. But they’re designed to work with operating systems that don’t use segmentation for protection.

Comment: regardless, the read operation would still have to survive page permissions, and the notion of  is supervisor is from the cpl not the (in this case) dpl of the fs register

Comment: @prl Good point! I've tested it and a CPL=3 program can use a DPL=0 descriptor with an RPL=0 selector. I guess Intel didn't bother doing additional checks with `sysexit`/`sysret` because by that time it was clear that paging was indeed the preferred protection mechanism.

Comment: @prl, thanks! Actually I'm just learning OS by reading Linux 0.11 since the code is easier and the course I learned uses Linux 0.11 as example and lab env. It is good to know the paging technique that modern OS adapts can avoid the issue. But it also means that semantically CPL <= DPL won't be checked for the instruction `mov %fs:(%eax), %ebx`, right?

Comment: @ChangdaLi No, it won't. I've tested it. But as I said, it's not easy to end up in that situation in the first place. If it happens, it's a bug on the OS side.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, got it, thanks for testing that! Great to know that my imaginary case won't happen because modern system is using paging for protection. And it is also great to know that the privilege level will not be tested for that specific instruction!